# Cannot create smtp session with google server

Tags: python

i'm learning python 3.6.0, and i was trying to create an email client.
I copied the code from a book, but it doesn't work. 
I get this error:

"TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connectio n failed because connected host has failed to respond"

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Listing 2
import getpass
import smtplib
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 587 # ssl port 465, tls port 587
def send_email(sender, recipient):
    """ Send email message """
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['Subject'] = input('Enter your email subject: ')
    message = input('Enter your email message. Press Enter when finished. ')
    part = MIMEText('text', "plain")
    part.set_payload(message)
    msg.attach(part)
    # create smtp session
    session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
    session.set_debuglevel(1)
    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo
    password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter you email password:")
    # login to server
    session.login(sender, password)
    # send mail
    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
    print("You email is sent to {0}.".format(recipient))
    session.quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sender = input("Enter sender email address: ")
    recipient = input("Enter recipeint email address: ")
    send_email(sender, recipient)
```

Can anybody help? Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code and it seems to work fine (I used my account credentials to send an email). You should check your Internet connectivity and firewall.

Comment: Thank you. My connectivity seems to work, and i disabled the firewall but still got that error. Will continue investigate...